# Use Symfony UniqueEntity with Doctrine

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine, unique

I am trying to get Symfony's UniqueEntity validator working for my Doctrine entities. The Symfony validator is already hooked up and working, the UniqueEntity from Symfony\Bridge, however, is more challenging, displaying this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'doctrine.orm.validator.unique' not found in /app/vendor/symfony/validator/Symfony/Component/Validator/ConstraintValidatorFactory.php on line 46
```

It appears as if the ValidatorFactory is requesting the UniqueEntity validator from the Symfony container, which I don't have because I am not using full stack symfony.

My entity looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints as AssertDoctrine;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id_UNIQUE", columns={"id"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="username_UNIQUE", columns={"username"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @AssertDoctrine\UniqueEntity("username")
 */
class User extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=45, unique=true, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=45)
     */
    protected $username;

    /** ... */
}
```

where AbstractEntity is a mapped superclass including a Trait that provides validation functionality for all entities:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Traits;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use App\Utility\Exception\ConstraintViolationException;

/**
 * A trait enabling validation of Doctrine entities to ensure invalid entities
 * don't reach the persistence layer.
 */
trait ValidatorAwareTrait
{
    public function validate()
    {
        $validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
            ->enableAnnotationMapping()
            ->getValidator();

        $violations = $validator->validate($this);

        // Count is used as this is not an array but a ConstraintViolationList
        if (count($violations) !== 0) {
            $message = $violations[0]->getPropertyPath() . ': ' . $violations[0]->getMessage();
            throw new ConstraintViolationException($message);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ref:

1. [DoctrineBridge\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity](https://github.com/symfony/DoctrineBridge/blob/master/Validator/Constraints/UniqueEntity.php)
2. [Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint](https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/master/Constraint.php)

I had this same issue a couple of months ago.

Short answer: You will not be able to use the `UniqueEntity` Validator without also using some type of DI which lists a service of `doctrine.orm.validator.unique` and translates this into `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntityValidator`.

Long answer: The error message you are seeing is the result of the fact that `DoctrineBridge\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity` reimplements `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint::validatedBy()`. In fact if you view the comment above `DoctrineBridge\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity::validatedBy()` you will see that it states "the validator must be defined as a service with this name" which is a lead to the fact that this validator is expected to be used with the Symfony `DependencyInjection` Component.

What isn't immediately apparent is that the service name that is being displayed within the error message is actually being defined within `Doctrine\DoctrineBundle\Resources\Config\Orm.xml`

Apologies for not providing the link to the `orm.xml` and the `dbal.xml` configuration files. My reputation does not currently allow for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
        ->setConstraintValidatorFactory($this->validatorFactory)
        ->enableAnnotationMapping()
        ->getValidator();

    $violations = $validator->validate($user);

    if (count($violations) !== 0) {
        $message = $violations[0]->getPropertyPath() . ': ' . $violations[0]->getMessage();
        throw new \Exception($message);
    }

    $this->entityManager->persist($user);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
```

Where $this->validatorFactory is service '@validator.validator_factory'

Comment: Could you provide some more details? Your answer is mostly code

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if validation is enabled in your config.yml:

```
framework:
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
```

Next, make sure you provide the required attribute *fields* in your unique annotation:

```
@AssertDoctrine\UniqueEntity(fields={"username"})
```

Last, if the previous steps still fail, you can provide your own unique validator service (See [original service for reference](https://github.com/symfony/DoctrineBridge/blob/master/Validator/Constraints/UniqueEntityValidator.php)) in the annotation as such:

```
@AssertDoctrine\UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, 
service="use.my.unique.validator.service")
```

You can even provide entity manager via the *em*-option in this annotation.