# Symfony test doctrine.orm.validator.unique problem

Tags: symfony

i want to test my form but I'm getting error **Class "doctrine.orm.validator.unique" not found**, this is about 
`#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['email'], message: 'There is already an account with this email')]` 
in my Entity. Can i add this in easy way like validator ? 
Test:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Tests\Form;

use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

class RegistrationFormTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    protected function getExtensions(): array
    {
        $validator = Validation::createValidator();

        // or if you also need to read constraints from annotations
        $validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
            ->enableAnnotationMapping()
            ->addDefaultDoctrineAnnotationReader()
            ->getValidator();

        return [
            new ValidatorExtension($validator),
        ];
    }


    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {
        $formData = [
            'email' => 'test@test.pl',
            'agreeTerms' => true
        ];
        $form = $this->factory->create(RegistrationFormType::class);
        $form->submit($formData);
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006250/class-doctrine-orm-validator-unique-not-found

Comment: This is not the same problem

Comment: Are you using the core framework, or stand-alone components? which version?

Comment: Please include where you use the UniqueEntity attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    $validator = $this->createMock('\Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface');
    $validator->method('validate')->will($this->returnValue(new ConstraintViolationList()));
    $formTypeExtension = new FormTypeValidatorExtension($validator);
    $coreExtension = new CoreExtension();

    $this->factory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
        ->addExtensions($this->getExtensions())
        ->addExtension($coreExtension)
        ->addTypeExtension($formTypeExtension)
        ->getFormFactory();
}
```

Comment: Can you add more explanation please? What was the root cause here?

Comment: I needed to mock validator in my test, because I had unique entity constraint(other too) in my entity.